# Two calls to GetListFeed fails (gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService())

Tags: python, google-docs, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using gdata-2.0.17.tar.gz.

Why does the following code fail on the second "for row in ssc.GetListFeed"?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gdata.spreadsheet.service

key = '1AjklhasdfLJK09j2f3nFLKnff9hf28fhGFAklnf8223'

ssc = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
ssc.email = 'something'
ssc.password = 'something'
ssc.ProgrammaticLogin()

for row in ssc.GetListFeed(key=key).entry:
    for key in row.custom:
        print str(key) + ':' + str(row.custom[key].text)
    print

for row in ssc.GetListFeed(key=key).entry:
    for key in row.custom:
        print str(key) + ':' + str(row.custom[key].text)
    print
```

The failure is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 16, in <module>
    for row in ssc.GetListFeed(key=key).entry:
  File "/home/someone/something/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py", line 252, in GetListFeed
    converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsListFeedFromString)
  File "/home/someone/something/gdata/service.py", line 1108, in Get
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 400, 'body': 'The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found. Make sure that you have the right URL and that the owner of the spreadsheet hasn&#39;t deleted it.', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}
```

Does the SpreadsheetsService object need to be reset between queries somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue here is the variable `key` - you are defining it here:

```
key = '1AjklhasdfLJK09j2f3nFLKnff9hf28fhGFAklnf8223'
```

But also here:

```
for key in row.custom:
```

Since the variable will retain its definition even after the loop exits, try changing the spreadsheet key variable name to something like `sheet_key` (or something better :) ) and see if it completes as expected. You can see the behavior in the code below:

```
In [1]: key = 'abcdef'

In [2]: for key in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: key
Out[3]: 'three'
```

Comment: Ah! I completely overlooked that I had reused that variable name! That was a mistake. Good catch, thanks a million!

Comment: @Allanrbo No problem at all - that can definitely be a tricky issue sometimes :)